# Setting String Length Limit then either substring or space filled

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

**Scenario**: I'm creating a file thats need to be in this format https://www.rbcroyalbank.com/ach/file-451771.pdf . I need to be able to set the limit of the string length for certain fields.

**Question**: Is there an easy way to set the limit of the field so that if the string was larger then the limit then just take the substring and if smaller would add extra spaces?

**Note**: I was able to accomplish something similar to this with integers by just using .toString("00000").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) in conjunction with the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) methods (where `5` could of course be variablized according to your needs):

```
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", "abcdefgh".PadRight(5).Substring(0, 5));
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", "abc".PadRight(5).Substring(0, 5));
```

prints:

```
'abcde'
'abc  '
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I figured it would be something simple but I couldn't find anything lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`string.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) or [`string.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx) to pad your strings with a char, and [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to limit it.

Answer (score 3):

This is straightforward.

```
const int MaxStringLength = 100;  /* set to your maximum length */
...
myString = (myString.Length >= MaxStringLength)
            ? myString.Substring(0, MaxStringLength)
            : myString.PadRight(MaxStringLength);
```